# How to convert arabic char into hexstring in java

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, char, arabic

The following code is returning in `??????` as output , when `str` has Arabic string :

```
String str="مرحبا",str2="";
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
                str2 += displayChar(str.charAt(reorder[i]));
                System.out.print(reorder[i]);
            }
   System.out.println(str2); // output is : ?????
```

and :

```
String displayChar(char c) {
        if (c < '\u0010') {
            return "0x0" + Integer.toHexString(c);
        } else if (c < '\u0020' || c >= '\u007f') {
            return "0x" + Integer.toHexString(c);
        } else {
            return c+"";
        }
    }
```

For 
    `reorder` is `integer` array only carries the new index (order) of the character in the given `str`

```
Here is the complete code, .. hope it will help you to understand the problem :
/*
 * (C) Copyright IBM Corp. 1999, All Rights Reserved
 *
 * version 1.0
 */

import java.io.*;

/**
 * A simple command-line interface to the BidiReference class.
 * <p>
 * This prompts the user for an ASCII string, runs the reference
 * algorithm on the string, and displays the results to the terminal.
 * An empty return to the prompt exits the program.
 * <p>
 * ASCII characters are preassigned various bidi direction types. 
 * These types can be displayed by the user for reference by
 * typing <code>-display</code> at the prompt.  More help can be
 * obtained by typing <code>-help</code> at the prompt.
 */
public class BidiReferenceTest {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new BufferedOutputStream(System.out));
    BidiReferenceTestCharmap charmap = BidiReferenceTestCharmap.TEST_ARABIC;
    byte baseDirection = -1;

    /**
     * Run the interactive test.
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new BidiReferenceTest().run();
    }

    void run() {
        //printHelp();

        while (true) {
            writer.print("> ");
            writer.flush();
            String input;
            try {
                input = reader.readLine();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                writer.println(e);
                continue;
            }

            if (input.length() == 0) {
                writer.println("Bye!");
                writer.flush();
                return;
            }

            if (input.charAt(0) == '-') { // command
                int limit = input.indexOf(' ');
                if (limit == -1) {
                    limit = input.length();
                }
                String cmd = input.substring(0, limit);
                if (cmd.equals("-display")) {
                    charmap.dumpInfo(writer);
                } else if (cmd.equals("-english")) {
                    charmap = BidiReferenceTestCharmap.TEST_ENGLISH;
                    charmap.dumpInfo(writer);
                } else if (cmd.equals("-hebrew")) {
                    charmap = BidiReferenceTestCharmap.TEST_HEBREW;
                    charmap.dumpInfo(writer);
                } else if (cmd.equals("-arabic")) {
                    charmap = BidiReferenceTestCharmap.TEST_ARABIC;
                    charmap.dumpInfo(writer);
                } else if (cmd.equals("-mixed")) {
                    charmap = BidiReferenceTestCharmap.TEST_MIXED;
                    charmap.dumpInfo(writer);
                } else if (cmd.equals("-baseLTR")) {
                    baseDirection = 0;
                } else if (cmd.equals("-baseRTL")) {
                    baseDirection = 1;
                } else if (cmd.equals("-baseDefault")) {
                    baseDirection = -1;
                } else {
                }
            } else {

                String ss= runSample(input);
                System.out.println(ss);
                Character.UnicodeBlock block =  Character.UnicodeBlock.of(Character.codePointAt(ss, 0));

            }
        }
    }



    String runSample(String str) {
        String str2 = "";
        try {
            charmap = BidiReferenceTestCharmap.TEST_ARABIC;

            byte[] codes = charmap.getCodes(str);
            baseDirection = 1;
            BidiReference bidi = new BidiReference(codes, baseDirection); // baseDirection = 1
            int[] reorder = bidi.getReordering(new int[] { codes.length });
            /*
            writer.println("base level: " + bidi.getBaseLevel() + (baseDirection != -1 ? " (forced)" : ""));

            // output original text
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
                displayChar(str.charAt(i));
            }
            writer.println();
             */
            // output visually ordered text
            for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i) {
                str2 += displayChar(str.charAt(reorder[i]));
                System.out.print(reorder[i]);
            }
            return str2;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            return "";
        }
    }

    String displayChar(char c) {
        if (c < '\u0010') {
            return "0x0" + Integer.toHexString(c);
        } else if (c < '\u0020' || c >= '\u007f') {
            return "0x" + Integer.toHexString(c);
        } else {
            return c+"";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're not doing anything with `str2`, and we've no idea what `reorder` is...

Comment: You're still not doing anything with `str2` though, and it seems that `reorder` is irrelevant to the question. Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem.

Comment: @JonSkeet the code has too long java class,  reorder has no effect on the attached code, it is only has integers represents the indexes of the char in the string, the problem is in displayChar(char c)

Comment: I didn't ask for the complete class you've got now. I asked for a short but complete program that demonstrates the problem. I've seen `displayChar` work, so I suspect the problem is actually elsewhere. If you're not willing to produce a short but complete program, I suspect I can't help you. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Answer (score 0):

One problem is that your terminal probably does not support Unicode characters correctly (this might not be the *only* problem).

Comment: I am using eclipse, how can I check it ?

Comment: no it prints ???? .. but when I wrote Arabic string in the code .. and save it as UTF-8 I got a new error IndexOutOFBound

Answer (score 0):

If I were to guess I'd say you run under Windows with the default console settings (i.e. Raster fonts) and you run the Java program from the console and not within Eclipse.

If that is the case, then just change the console settings to use a TrueType font (Lucida Console or Consolas) and you should see boxes instead of question marks. Those won't look right either, but at least it's the actual text instead of question marks.

Side note: Question marks are a common occurrence if something *does* support Unicode but converts it into another encoding somewhere, e.g. Latin 1.